# Деструктурирующее присваивание в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Пожалуйста, помогите понять логику.

Дано:

```
const stats = {
  max: 56.78,
  standard_deviation: 4.34,
  median: 34.54,
  mode: 23.87,
  min: -0.75,
  average: 35.85
};

const half = ({max, min}) => (max + min) / 2.0;
```

Как программа знает, откуда брать "max" и "min", если переменная "stats" в последней строке не упоминается?

Answer (score 3):

> **Деструктуризация** или **Деструктурирующее присваивание** - это синтаксис, которым можно извлечь значения из массива или объекта в переменные(когда нам так удобнее работать)

Деструктуризация массива

```js
const arr = ['деструктурируемый', 'массив', 'непонятно как', 'отображается'];
const [a1, a2] = arr;
const [b1, b2, , b3, b4] = arr;

console.log(a1, a2);
console.log(b1, b2, b3, b4);
```

Деструктуризация объекта

```js
const obj = {
    name: 'деструктурируемый',
    type: 'объект',
    action: 'выведен'
}
const {name, type, action, res} = obj; // Имена переменных должны соответствовать ключам из объекта
console.log(name, type, action, res)
```

---

По вашему вопросу:

```js
// Это ваш объект
const stats = {
  max: 56.78,
  standard_deviation: 4.34,
  median: 34.54,
  mode: 23.87,
  min: -0.75,
  average: 35.85
};

// Это объявление функции, где на вход подается объект и деструктурируется в переменные max и min
const half = ({max, min}) => (max + min) / 2.0;
// Если ее вызвать, передав объект, то произойдет деструктуризация объекта 
// и внутри функции будут доступны 2 переменные max и min
// результат выполнения функции возвращается

// Другая запись данной стрелочной функции без деструктуризации
const half2 = (obj) => (obj.max + obj.min) / 2.0;

// Обычная функция
function half3 ({max, min}) {
    return (max + min) / 2.0;
}

console.log(1, half(stats));
console.log(2, half2(stats));
console.log(3, half3(stats));
```

Comment: На самом деле тут нет ответа на заданный вопрос))

Comment: То есть, в момент объявления фрагментом ({max, min})  мы указываем, что именно нужно будет взять из массива для последующих вычислений. Так?

Comment: Ну по сути да. В функции указывается, что из объекта, который будет передан в функцию в качестве аргумента, необходимо взять 2 ключа min, max. Они будут доступны в функции как обычные переменные

Answer (score 1):

Программа и не знает ещё ничего, потому что это всего лишь объявление функции, а не её вызов и работа с ней. Тут пока что ничего не происходит. Даже если полностью удалить весь объект `stats` из текущего кода - ничего не поменяется

Comment: Это аналог `lambda` из других языков?

Comment: Да, она самая...

Comment: Понятнее не стало

Comment: @Хрумский Это объявление анонимной функции. Она не выполняется в вашем коде, а только объявляется. Чтобы её выполнить нужно её вызвать, наверное так: `half(stats)`, хотя возможно и не совсем так.

Comment: @Хрумский `const half = ({max, min}) => (max + min) / 2.0;` - объявление функции, которая принимает в качестве параметра какой-либо объект, деструктурирует его, то есть ищет в объекте поля с именами _max_ и _min_ и найденные значения использует для выполнения своего кода. Вызывается функция так - `half(stats)`

Comment: @Хрумский а что именно не ясно? это объявление функции. stats тут никак не задействован от слова совсем........ а если написать так `half(stats)` то тогда будет........ однако вместо stats можно передать любой объект ....сам stats тут ни при чём