# Как понять, когда использовать Common JS, а когда ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, commonjs

Ещё плаваю в теме модулей JS. 
Столкнулась с двумя разными форматами: Common JS и ES6. Как я поняла, что Common JS уже реже используется.
Мне не понятно, как определить, какой формат использовать.

Например, устанавливаю библиотеку. Создаю js файл и мне нужно подключить эту библиотеку.
Так как я в теории научилась подключать с помощью ES6 я пишу: `import { Lib } from 'библиотека';`. 
Мне выдаётся ошибка. Понимаю, что в библиотеке нет экспорта по умолчанию и переписываю так: `import * as Lib from 'библиотека';`. 
А потом при использовании пишу так `Lib.default`.

Подключение работает, но выглядит подозрительно неправильно. Его можно было написать и в стиле Common JS `const Lib = require('библиотека');`, что выглядит эстетичнее.

Подскажите, какой формат лучше использовать и когда?
Если я не правильно задаю вопрос. В плане, что это несравнимые вещи, прощу поправить и толкнуть в правильном направлении.

Спасибо!

Comment: `import Lib from 'библиотека';` - Должно работать так, это как раз экспорт по умолчанию. Когда идет перечисление множества экспортируемых данных, то используется при импорте деструктуризация объекта. [Примеры деструктурирующего присваивания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1463147/1463324#1463324) можно посмотреть здесь

Comment: Ну это как использовать холодильник "ЗИЛ" и какой-нибудь Samsung прошлогоднего года выпуска – вроде бы морозят одинаково, но удобств во втором явно больше. Тут ровно то же самое: `import` новый, может только конкретное что-то выгрузить, `require` выгрузит всё подряд. Насчёт "эстетичнее" – спорное утверждение, импорты всегда наверху, как у всех нормальных ЯП, require черт пойми где, ещё и переменную заводить надо.